# Value of this inside createReactClass and (React) class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The value of `this` inside `createReactClass({})` is different from the value of `this` inside a React class: In the first one, since it is not undefined, I can use  `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)` to find my current node. However, I can't do that within a proper React class, as `this` inside a React class gets an undefined value and `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)` returns null.

I need to find/get my current node. Any solution?

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: I just figured it out. I just used an arrow function, where I was using the 'this' and everything worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, just use an arrow function, and the this will be bound to the current React Component.